# EmberJS - setting ArrayController's itemController explicitly

Tags: ember.js

The docs here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_itemController state that I can do this:

```
App.MyArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    //Item Controller Implementation
  })
});
```

But when I tried that in my application, I get this error:

> Error while processing route: index Could not resolve itemController: "(subclass of Ember.ObjectController)" Error: Could not resolve itemController: "(subclass of Ember.ObjectController)"

I'm using Ember.js 1.9.1.

Here's a JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuvolumumo/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Please show us your implementation of this.

Comment: @BuckDoyle JSBin is here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuvolumumo/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation was outdated, this feature has never landed in some release. Look this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10217) for more info.

You will need to give a name for your controller, and reference it in `itemController` like the following:

```
App.MyItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

App.MyArrayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'myItem'
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: heh I just saw your pull request to update the documentation and thought “probably looking at the same question!” @nnyby: like [Tom Dale says in the thread for this feature](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/5301#issuecomment-65857454), you should be moving from item controllers to components.